# Add html to WooCommerce category shortcode output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, shortcode

How can I filter the output of the WooCommerce `'product categories'` shortcode. I need to add a button into each product in the loop.

[Docs WooCommerce: Product Categories shortcode](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-13)

[WooCommerce code source *(github)*: class-wc-shortcodes.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php)

It should work. The syntax is strange for me and I'm not sure about how I am supposed to change `{$product_categories}` syntax code in it:

```
function add_html_to_shortcode_product_categories() {

  echo '<a class = "cta_btn" href="#">shop now</a>';

}

add_action('woocommerce_shortcode_after_{$product_categories}_loop', 'add_html_to_shortcode_product_categories', 20);
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

with categories. We need to hook on to woocommerce_after_subcategory_title

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title','add_btn');

function add_btn() {

  echo '<span class = "cta_btn">SHOP NOW</span>';

}
```